# MVC 3 Dynamic View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, dynamic, view

I am fairly new to MVC (3) and am building an app which will use lists of various data items throughout.

I can build a view for each, but thought as each will be similar (HTML table with columns of data) it would make more sense to use a common view.

The controllers all use Linq from a DAL to return entries eg

*DAL*

```
public List <MyObject> getAllEntriesOfSomeType()
{
    var myobjects = from r in db.something
                    where r.status ==1
                    select r;
    return myobjects.ToList();
}
```

*CONTROLLER*

```
MyObjectClass o = new MyObjectClass();

return View(o.getAllEntriesOfSomeType());
```

*VIEW*

in the view, which would not be tied to this object, I would like to show the column names and data dynamically eg something like

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        @int cols = 0;
        @foreach(c in Model.Columns)
        {
            <th>
                @cols+=1;
                @c.DisplayName
            </th>
        }
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

@foreach(m in Model)
{
    <tr>
        @(int i = 1;i<=cols;i++)
        {
            <td>
                @m[i].Value
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

...

Is there any (simple!) way of achieving the above. I thought of converting the model to DataTable but there didn't seem to be an easy way (read something about ObjectShredder)

Answer (score 0):

MVC really is about having a distinct view for each set of data you want to display/edit.

This is so that when things change (and they will) you have that separation that allows you to change a view or page without affecting the others.

That said it doesn't mean you cant be clever about what you are doing.

If you are saying that your data is all very similar, well then you would have a problem with them all inheriting from the same interface or base type right?

Like:

```
public class MyObjectClass : IMyObjectClassCommonStuff
{  
}
```

Then in your **partial** view (so that you can reuse the data display on different pages), you can use the model in your view like this:

```
@model IList<IMyObjectClassCommonStuff>
```

You can then write your view as normal referencing the common fields from the interface.